# C# Windows form Chart fixed axis?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, charts, axis

I am very new in all this of programming and I am beginning with C# 
now I have an application which should show some points in a chart, but i would like to fix the x and y axis in a way that the graph area always has as  minimum 50 and maximum 50, but  the graphic area doesn't auto-fit the graph, I don't know if I explain it well, I mean I want the points for x and y axis always display from 0 to 50. does some one know how to set this?

Comment: you want to fit x-axis min as zero,max of 50 for fixed set of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can easily set limits like this:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 50;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 50;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 0;
```

Comment: Nice, I have to read a little more about the configuration of chart, there are a lot of options still don't know how to use properly  thank you so much!~